# code to format text input to 2 decimal places before computation

Tags: javascript, beginner, formatting

I have this piece of code that checks the input of a text box before I compute for my main logic. This looks like it should be refactored but I'm currently stumped how to do so. The only thing that comes to mind is to make 2 functions "processDecimal" and "processInt" and I just copy the code under their respective if condition but it just feels wrong. Any help?

```
function inputChanges(element) {
  let elm = document.getElementById(element.id);
  let val = elm.value;
  let isDecimal = elm.hasAttribute("decimal") ? true : false;
  if (isDecimal) {
    if (parseFloat(val) == 0 || val == "") {
      elm.value = "0.00";
    } else {
      elm.value = isNaN(parseFloat(val)) ? "0.00" : parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
    }
  }else {
    if (parseInt(val) == 0 || val == "") {
      elm.value = "0";
    } else {
      elm.value = isNaN(parseInt(val)) ? "0" : parseInt(val);
    }
  }
  computeTemperature();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

```
    if (parseFloat(val) == 0 || val == "") {
      elm.value = "0.00";
    } else {
      elm.value = isNaN(parseFloat(val)) ? "0.00" : parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
    }
```

is redundant. You can simply use `elm.value = isNaN(parseFloat(val)) ? "0.00" : parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);`.

The same holds true for the integer evaluation. This

```
    if (parseInt(val) == 0 || val == "") {
      elm.value = "0";
    } else {
      elm.value = isNaN(parseInt(val)) ? "0" : parseInt(val);
    }
```

can be reduced to `elm.value = isNaN(parseInt(val)) ? "0" : parseInt(val);`

From a "Code Smell" perspective, it reduces cognitive complexity by reducing the number of logical paths